# Linq Select row Where date in Current month

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I need to get data from the current month.Haven't been able to find a solution that works.

This is my code, which gives me the data I need, but I get data from a whole month back, instead of from the current month we are in.

I chose the date "limit" twice with `row > DateTime.Today.Addmonths(-1)`

Any ideas ?

```
var userQuery = 
from timeEntry in TimeEntries
                                //this displays a month back, not current month TODO: change to current month.
where timeEntry.DateEntity > DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1)
select new {
    UserName = timeEntry.User.FirstName + " " +timeEntry.User.LastName,
    HoursEntered = timeEntry.HoursEntered,       
    User = timeEntry.User
};

var localrows = userQuery.ToList();

var grouping = localrows.GroupBy(x => x.User);

var userList = grouping.Select(q => new {
    UserName = q.FirstOrDefault().UserName,
    Hours = q.Sum(hr => hr.HoursEntered),                 //AbsenceTypeID = holiday(1)                          // still takes from a whole month, instead of current month.
    Holiday = q.FirstOrDefault().User.Absences.Where(a => a.AbsenceTypeID == 1).Where(date => date.DateEntity > DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1)).Count(),
});
```

EDIT:

Keyur patel' answer worked, though not for the bottom one.

so there i have to thank Jules for this one:

```
DateTime.Today.AddDays((DateTime.Today.Day -1) * -1)
```

Comment: Do you want data from (edit for -> from) the first day of the month?

Comment: i want data that matches for this month, so if it's the 21/9, i want data from 1/9 to 21/9. so data from just the month we are in.

Comment: Use this DateTime.Today.AddDays((DateTime.Today.Day -1) * -1)

Comment: that works ^^ thx.

Comment: Click up vote on the comment so others will know the answer.

Comment: how do i upvote a comment ? isn't it only "answers" i can upvote ?

Comment: Ahh, You may not have enough point to up vote the comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using this:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
var userQuery = 
from timeEntry in TimeEntries
where timeEntry.DateEntity.Month == today.Month && timeEntry.DateEntity.Year == today.Year
select new {
    UserName = timeEntry.User.FirstName + " " +timeEntry.User.LastName,
    HoursEntered = timeEntry.HoursEntered,       
    User = timeEntry.User
};
```

Added check for `.Year` since it may match with months from other years, if you have any.

**Edit**

As for the holiday part:

```
var userList = grouping.Select(q => new {
    UserName = q.FirstOrDefault().UserName,
    Hours = q.Sum(hr => hr.HoursEntered),
    Holiday = q.FirstOrDefault().User.Absences.Where(a => a.AbsenceTypeID == 1 && a.DateEntity.Month == today.Month && a.DateEntity.Year == today.Year).Count(),
});
```

Comment: Yes, I missed the second part, try my edited version and let me know if that didn't work.

Comment: got it working with combining your method and the one from Jules.    Your second part doesn't work for me, keeps throwing errors at me ^^

Comment: The only way the first one works and second doesn't is if the `DateTime` is nullable for your other table. (If so use `a.DateEntity.Value.Month` and same for Year). Anyways, I'm glad you got it working! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply compare only Month part of the date like this:

```
timeEntry.DateEntity.Month == DateTime.Now.Month
```

Comment: this will return 'true' for different years

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Month` and `Year` properties of the DateTime class as follows:

```
var userQuery = TimeEntries
  .Where (te => te.DateEntity.Month == DateTime.Today.Month && te.DateEntity.Year == DateTime.Today.Year)
  .Select(timeEntry => 
    new {
      UserName = timeEntry.User.FirstName + " " + timeEntry.User.LastName,
      HoursEntered = timeEntry.HoursEntered,       
      User = timeEntry.User
    }
  );
```

Comment: instead of checking current month again and again in query, select the month in some variable
var currentMonth = DateTime.Today.Month;
var currentYear = DateTime.Today.Year;

and then
.Where (te => te.DateEntity.Month == currentMonth && te.DateEntity.Year == currentYear)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
`.Where(x => x.EntityDate >= new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1));`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29984019)