# How to match a specific string inside a string fetched from database in MVC 5?

Tags: sql-server, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

So I am building a project where I need to fetch date from the database and on the basis of the given month,
as I need to find customers who have birthday on the given month. I have a query that works perfectly fine in the SQL server but I don't get its equivalent in Linq.

So here is my query that runs in SQL

```
SELECT * FROM CustReg 
WHERE DOB LIKE '_____month%'
```

I need to match that month as it should come in the 6th position of that DOB string.

```
Demo Database-
Id    Name    DOB
1     AB      1995-02-20
2     CD      1998-04-13
4     EF      1991-02-15
5     GH      1988-06-8
6     IJ      2000-02-09
```

Query - Select all Employee whose birthday comes on feb.
Expected Output - AB,EF,IJ.

PS- I have taken datatype of DOB `string` not `Date` or `DateTime`.
I also have month in string (for eg '02' for feb)that I have fetched from the input date.

Comment: Can you please share your input and expected output ?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari: Why don't you use `MONTH(your_date)` in sql query to match your month?? For `LINQ` I think your question is same as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609777/linq-select-row-where-date-in-current-month

Comment: @Irfan because i have taken  string as a datatype for that field not date or datetime.

Comment: @xXx i have edited my question , please check again

Comment: Fix your database and store DOB as a proper date type.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question right, may be the following code helps.

First create a enum of Months,

```
public enum Month
{
   Jan=1,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,July,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec
}
```

Now use the following query to get what u wanted,

```
Month requiredMonth = Month.Feb;
var res = CustReg.Where(x => (Month)Enum.Parse(typeof(Month), x.DOB.Substring(5, 2)) == requiredMonth).Select(x => x.Name);
foreach (var item in res)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```